# How to fix python3 instalation on linux mint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, linux-mint

So I've been using linux mint mate for a while, and everything was working fine. 
So as I got a new notebook, I installed the new version of linux mint (19.2 - Tina) alongside the windows 10. Everything went right, I think.

Now, I'm trying to get it ready for use, and it's not working.

It supposedly came with both versions of python:

- Python 2.7.15+
- Python 3.6.8

But when I tried to run a simple hello world, but importing the essentials packages for me, something like this

```
import numpy as np
import math #as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.switch_backend('agg')
import sys
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import powerlaw as pl
from itertools import zip_longest
import csv
import os

print('hello world')
```

It didn't even recognize the numpy package, and I got the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testes.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

So I went to this website and tried following the tutorial

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#id18

But when I tried to install numpy the result was as bellow:

```
(tutorial_env) jheniffer@jheniffer-5480:~/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi$ pip install python3-numpy
Collecting python3-numpy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/jheniffer/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi/tutorial_env/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/python3-numpy/
```

I don't know what should I do to get this running, 
how should I proceed to install everything, because I thought that the basic packages, like numpy for example, was already installed, and every other time that I tried installing something by pip (on my previous laptop) it worked with just

`pip3 install python3-numpy`

I tried the option without pip, it installed successfully

```
(tutorial_env) jheniffer@jheniffer-5480:~/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi$ sudo apt install python3-numpy
[sudo] password for jheniffer:             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  gfortran python-numpy-doc python3-dev python3-nose python3-numpy-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-numpy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 287 not upgraded.
Need to get 1.943 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10,9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-numpy amd64 1:1.13.3-2ubuntu1 [1.943 kB]
Fetched 1.943 kB in 4s (528 kB/s)          
Selecting previously unselected package python3-numpy.
(Reading database ... 308507 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-numpy_1%3a1.13.3-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-numpy (1:1.13.3-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-numpy (1:1.13.3-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

But when I tried to run the hello word code, I got this message again

```
(tutorial_env) jheniffer@jheniffer-5480:~/Dropbox/teste_cros_bi$ python3 testes.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testes.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/509630

Comment: Are you confusing the Debian / Mint _apt_-installable system package `python3-numpy` with its corresponding Python / PyPI _pip_-installable project `numpy`?

Comment: Maybe, what is the difference? I tried installing it without the pip, like this: sudo apt install python3-numpy, it installed, but i's not working either

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using the `apt` package name in `pip` as opposed to the name of the PyPi package. First, check the default versions for pip and python on your system. This can be done using `pip --version` and `python --version`. If both are defaulting to Python 2.7 (which they very well might be), I would strongly recommend using Python 3.6 if possible, as Python 2.7 will reach EOL in 2020.

You can do this explicitly by using `pip3` and `python3` via the command line. To install numpy for Python 3, use `pip3 install numpy`. Keep in mind that this will only install it for Python 3, so if you spin up Python 2.7 interpreter, it will not be installed.

In the future, if you want to find the name of a PyPi package for install, you can do `pip search {QUERY}`, like `pip search numpy` for example.